# sequelize for Node.js : ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm new to sequelize and Node.js.
I coded for test sequelize, but error occured **"ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE : Table 'db.node_tests' doesn't exist"**
Error is very simple. 
However, I want to get data from "**node_test**" table.
I think sequelize appends 's' character.

There is my source code.

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

var sequelize = new Sequelize('db', 'user', 'pass');
var nodeTest = sequelize.define('node_test',
        { uid: Sequelize.INTEGER 
         , val: Sequelize.STRING} );

nodeTest.find({where:{uid:'1'}})
    .success(function(tbl){
        console.log(tbl);
    });
```

I already create table "node_test", and inserted data using mysql client.

Does I misunderstood usage?

Comment: I'm using Mysql 5.5.28 / sequelize 1.6.0-beta4 / Node.js 0.8.15.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the answer my own question.

I appended Sequelize method option following. `{define:{freezeTableName:true}}`

**Then sequelize not appends 's' character after table name.**

Answer (score 13):

Though the answer works nicely, I nowadays recommend the use of the `tableName` option when declaring the model:

```
sequelize.define('node_test', { 
  uid: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  val: Sequelize.STRING
}, {
   tableName: 'node_test'
});
```

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html

Comment: Thank you for your new answer. I'll try it. :)

Comment: @sdepold You may wish to update the link to the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

Sequelize is using by default the plural of the passed model name. So it will look for the table "node_tests" or "NodeTests". Also it can create the table for you if you want that.

```
nodeTest.sync().success(function() {
  // here comes your find command.
})
```

Sync will try to create the table if it does not already exist. You can also drop the existing table and create a new one from scratch by using `sync({ force: true })`. Check the SQL commands on your command line for more details about what is going on.

Comment: you are welcome. let me know if you need further information.

Comment: just a side not: `dresende/node-orm2` module gave me the same `Error: ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE`...
you need to call `sync()` for the first time, before adding data.

Answer (score 2):

When you define a model to an **existing** table, you need to set two *options* for sequelize to:

1. find your table name *as-is* and
2. not fret about sequelize's default columns *updatedAt* and *createdAt* that it expects.

Simply add both options like so:

```
var nodeTest = sequelize.define('node_test',
        { uid: Sequelize.INTEGER , val: Sequelize.STRING},
        { freezeTableName: true , timestamps: false} //add both options here
);
```

Note the *options* parameter:

```
    sequelize.define('name_of_your_table',
    {attributes_of_your_table_columns},
    {options}
     );
```

Missing either options triggers respective errors when using sequelize methods such as nodeTest.*findAll()*.

```
> ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE    //freezeTableName
> ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR  //timestamps
```

Alternatively, you can:

1. create a fresh table through sequelize. It will append "s" to the table name and create two timestamp columns as defaults or
2. use [sequelize-auto](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto), an awesome npm package to generate sequelize models from your existing database programmatically.

Here's the sequelize [documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/docs/models-definition/#configuration) for option configurations.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was due to case. I was having:

```
sequelize.define('User', {
```

The correct way is to use lowercase:

```
sequelize.define('user', {
```